# How to update Kivy GridLayout "rows" property in dynamic class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Suppose I have this in my .kv file:

```
<VerticalLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1

<Root>:
    VerticalLayout:
        rows: len(self.children)
        Button:
            text: 'Sample 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Sample 2'
        Button:
            text: 'Sample 3'
```

It works perfectly like that. But what I want to to is add the "rows" part that updates automatically based on the children in the layout to the dynamic class, like this:

```
<VerticalLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: len(self.children)
```

But when I do that it doesn't work! How can I get this functionality inside of the Kivy Language without anything in my .py file?

Comment: Adding a row dynamically to a GridLayout is a one-line python statement:
`self.mylayout.rows += 1`
Is that something you still don't want to do? If subtracting rows like this, you'll need to remove widgets that may be occupying them.